# Map Subdomain to specific AppEngine app version

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

I have a Python app at www.example.com. I want to create a subdomain that will map to a different version of my app (actually a Java app). So want I want to do is:
www.example.com -> example.appspot.com [0]
subdomain.example.com -> subdomain.example.appspot.com [?]

Is it doable??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do this, except with a reverse proxy in front of your app (or by using your main version as such a reverse proxy).

Comment: Not very elegant! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Lumpy What do you want to know exactly? If you have a specific question, you should post it as one.